# this def function I've made does not output the value specified by print

Tags: python, function

I've made this simple program that uses a def function to output one of the components of a list. The component isn't being printed as specified in the code, which is really confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Members = ["fine", "Mine"]
def Helpers():
    print("Helpers who wanna work work work")
    for record in Members:
        if(record[0] == "fine"):
            print(record[1])
      
Helpers()
```

Comment: `for record in Members:` says *"for each element in the list `Members` set the variable `record` to the value of the element"*. Since your list is one-dimensional, then `record` will be a string. Therefore `record[0]` isn't right. Instead `if(record == "fine"):` is what you are looking for.

Comment: `record` will be `"fine"` on the first iteration of your loop, and `"Mine"` on the second iteration.  `record[0]` will therefore be `"f"` and `"M"`, respectively.  You will note that *neither* of those values is equal to `"fine"`...

Comment: This is that situation you need to embed some debugging `print` statements in your code. print `record` in every iteration to see what it is, and what you except from `record[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

your problem that you use index on `record` that take the first letter position

you should run withou index

```py
Members = ["fine", "Mine"]
def Helpers():
    print("Helpers who wanna work work work")
    for record in Members:
        if(record == "fine"):
            print(record)
      
Helpers()
```